# Mini-filter warning dialog when copy larger file to drive?

Tags: driver, minifilter

I am developing a mini-filter drive to get full path of file when user drag & drop to drive.

1. I have a file: C:\folder\text.txt
2. I drag & drop this file to D:\
3. Mini-Filter will get "C:\folder\text.txt"
4. Mini-Filter intercept creating file D:\text.txt

I have done with this. But when I drag & drop a large file to drive

1. My file'size is 1GB
2. My drive space is free < 1GB (100MB, 200M , so on)

Windows will show the warning dialog as below:

[image]

**How can I do to prevent this dialog showing?**

Comment: This looks like a filesystem issue. If the the drive you are dragging into is not NTFS, then this is your problem. As it can't handle large files. This is not a question regarding mini-filter drivers at all.